# Oracle Total (elapsed) time of all queries of a day

Tags: sql, oracle, monitoring

I need to report the total time of all queries executed by a certain module in one day.

```
    -- sum over all queries executed the last 24 hours
   select
         u.username,
         sum(round(v.ELAPSED_TIME / 3600000000 * 60,2)) ELAPSED_TIME_MINUTES,
         sum(round(v.ELAPSED_TIME / 3600000000,2)) ELAPSED_TIME_HOURS,
         v.module
      from gv$sql v
      left join dba_users u
    on v.parsing_user_id = u.user_id
       where u.username like '%XYZ' and module = 'WEBSERVER'
  and to_date(v.FIRST_LOAD_TIME,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') > (trunc(sysdate,'DD') - interval '1' day)
  group by username,module;
```

But I am aksing myself the following:

1. has v$sql all the queries and how long? it is at least empty after flushing the shared pool
2. is there a better way to calculate to total time consumed by queries in a certain timeframe?
3. is FIRST_LOAD_TIME the right field to find the correct day.  According to Oracle it is a Timestamp of the parent creation time - should be correct?

Thank you for joining a discussion!

Comment: Your question may be more related to db admin than typical programming. Maybe you could ask it on dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: `v$sql` just has the currently cached query plans.  A plan might be in the cache for a minute or an hour or a day.  Are you licensed to use the AWR?

Comment: @JustinCave: yes, AWR is licenced

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what possible use such a number would produce?  It seems to me that it is such an aggregate of so much unrelated activity as to be useless.

Answer (score 0):

1. Rows in V$SQL for certain statements disappear after they complete, either due to hints, or due to the nature of the sql statement, such as `CREATE TABLE` goes away.
2. If you are setting the `MODULE` via `DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE(mod_name, action_name);` and have SQL tuning licensed, then just user the Automatic Workload Management (AWR) framework; it includes the MODULE information in the reports it can produce, and gives you number of executions, plus lots of other information.
3. `FIRST_LOAD_TIME` could be days ago, or a few moments ago.

I would stay away from V$SQL -- it is too dynamic for what you want to do; and use the `SET_MODULE` to set the module name, and possibly set a different action name for different parts of your code.